# How to turn DXF into image and add it into MS Word?

Tags: autocad, cad, dxf, wmf

I have DXF files like this:

[image]

And I want to copy it into MS Word, like this:
[image]

How can I do it?

How I do it manually:
Open DXF file by `AutoCad`, Copy the `DXF` using `BetterWMF`, `BetterWMF` will turn it into image and I can then paste it in `MS Word`, and then adjust the size of the image.

I thought about turn `DXF` to `WMF`, but I didn't find any python package about turning `DXF` to `WMF`.

Comment: I never used, but you might find some tools/libraries to convert between DXF and image formats. Now you if you have AutoCAD installed, you can automate this conversion process. Would that work?

Comment: What about using copy (Ctrl + C) in AutoCAD and then Paste Special in Word?  If that doesn't give you the right results, have you tried PNGOUT?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a .dxf into word by first opening the .dxf with visio, then copying the image in visio to word. It's still a bit clunky, but it works.